# Why shouldn't an event pertain to multiple aggregates?

Tags: event-sourcing

In my experience, it is often said that in event sourcing "an event must belong to one aggregate" and also "an aggregate is your biggest transactional boundary".

Why is this?

What harm would come of events like this:

```js
{
  type: "BoblesSent"
  aggregates: [1, 2],
  from: 1,
  to: 2,
  amount: 420
}
```

Seems like it could be atomically recorded, efficiently queried when reconstructing just one (either) aggregate, and applied in isolation in both push/projection and lazy/reconstruction scenarios.

Where is the catch? Is it a performance scalability thing?

Can also be heterogeneous aggregates:

```js
{
  type: "ActivityCreated",
  aggregates: [1, 999],
  customer: 1,
  activity: 999
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having an event that references more than one aggregate.

Trying to write changes into two different shared data structures, atomically... that's a real problem.

Comment: If you store once and query always, design aroud your query pattern.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason thank you for your comment. However, I am a little confused: When would I need to write the changes to the two data structures atomically? When handling the `"SendBobles"` command the handler would "optimistically lock" (via conditional write) against new events pertaining to either aggregate, retrying the business logic if either changed. When making a queryable projection, as opposed to an aggregate model, eventual consistency is expected.

Comment: It looks like this is about a specific development tool or library that has its own terminology. Please add the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 1):

> "an aggregate is your biggest transactional boundary" Why is this?

Because if you increase your transactional boundary (say multiple aggregates or even database-level) then you will end up with consistency issues.  To deal with those issues you will then need to introduce locks and those will hurt scalability and increase complexity.

In ES you favor eventual consistency between aggregates and strong consistency within a single aggregate.  This means that you should model your application in such a way that each aggregate encapsulates all rules of a business entity (According to your domain).

When you save the mentioned event 'BoblesSent', how do you guarantee consistency of both aggregates?  What if you save the event but one of the two aggregates has already saved another event in parallel.  I'm assuming you are also storing the version number of the event - so to guarantee consistency (i.e guarantee that another event has not been saved with the same version number in parallel) you are using transactions that are locking both aggregates which may or may not prove to be a scalability concern (depending on your use case).

Also, how do you efficiently query it when re-constructing the aggregates?  Depending on your data service, this might require cross-partition queries (Because the events of the two aggregates might rely on different partitions).  Usually when querying the events of an aggregate you use its id as the partition key to guarantee that the search hits only a single partition.  Again, depending on your use case this might not be acceptable performance-wise.

Comment: So, it's about sharding the event stream?